# how to loop through a certain number at a time $wpdb results php wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a query that returns over 7000 records.
I'd like to loop through the results like for example 100 at a time because it's so large and will take so long.
How should I do this? I think the get_results returns an object and I'm not sure how to loop through this and get the data unless it's a foreach loop (only way I've ever done it for wordpress queries).  Any advise is appreciated. Thank you.

```
    $arr_megadomain = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT urlid, content FROM `megadomains` WHERE xstatus = 'subdomainlist'");
if ($arr_megadomain) {
    foreach ($arr_megadomain as $domain) {
       // My long code here.
}
```

Comment: First you should learn to parameterize your queries to avoid SQL injection, but having said that, try using `OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY` at the end of your query.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks.  I didn't even think about doing it that way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get a count of the results, then loop through using LIMIT.

```
 $arr_megadomain = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT urlid, content FROM `megadomains` WHERE xstatus = 'subdomainlist' LIMIT 100");
```

Next loop:

```
 $arr_megadomain = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT urlid, content FROM `megadomains` WHERE xstatus = 'subdomainlist' LIMIT 101, 200");
```